# Django - Primary Key field related to foreign key

Tags: django

I want the instances of Feature model that share a foreign key to have an id. When a new feature would be created, I want to auto-increment that id.

[image]

If you take a look at this print from the feature table in the database, each feature has a foreign key (shapefile_id) and those who share the same shapefile_id, they have a unique id (id_relat)

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle this than what I have found so far:

```
class Shapefile(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Feature(models.Model):
    shapefile = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
    id_relat = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)

    def Meta(self):
        unique_together = (("shapefile", "id_relat"),)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id_relat: #assign incremented id only to new feature
            self.id_relat = cal_id_relat(self.shapefile)
        super(Feature, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def cal_id_relat(shapefile):
    ids_relat = Feature.objects.filter(shapefile=shapefile).order_by('-id_relat').values_list('id_relat',flat=True)
    if ids_relat:
        return ids_relat[0]+1
    else:
        return 0
```

What I dont like in this, it's the necessity to query all the features to get the highest id_relat in the cal_id_relat method.

Comment: Try AutoField instead PositiveIntegerField.

Comment: Do you really need to use id_relat field? Every of your models have the field id, which is positive, integer and 100% unique.

Comment: id_relat is an id specific and unique to Features that share the same shapefile foreign key. two features can have the same id_relat if the foreign key is different

Comment: Couldn't it be a ForeignKey to ShapeFile then?.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't get what exactly you want to reach by using id_relat field. It doesn't add uniqueness (because we already have primary key), it could be easy calculated if there is some need in enumeration.

Comment: its like if you subset features based on the foreign key and give a new id starting with 0 to those features, this id is used to be shown to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Django application could be executed in >1 threads, so your approach is potentially dangerous. cal_id_relat could be called simultaneously and will return the same id for all calls.